# dynamic memory allocation segfault

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Why does my code segfault when using the dynamic memory allocation in the code below ?Any pointers on what maybe happening? , im using valgrind and it points to the second loop being the issue .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int x , y;

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);

    int** b= new int*[y];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < y; i++)
    {
        b[i] = new int[x];
    }

    //Problem at this loop area according to valgrind
    for(int i = 0 ; i < y ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < x ; j++)
        {
            b[y][x] = 0;
        }
    }

    cout<<b[0][0]<<endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < y; i++)
        {
            delete b[i];
        }

    delete [] b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo?  `b[y][x] = 0;` --> `b[i][j] = 0;` .

Comment: `new T[]` -> `delete[]`. so `delete [] b[i];`.

Comment: BTW, `std::vector` would avoid manual memory management.

Comment: You got it , ty :) ,need more sleep :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax? `b[y][x] = 0` and not `b[i][j] = 0` ?

`b[y][x]` is out of range.

while `b[y-1][x-1]` is the last matrix index.